# How to set "xml:lang" attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2006

I need to add a `xml:lang` attribute on the root xml node in the outbound document from BizTalk.

This is a fixed value, so it may be set in the schema or something.

This is what I want to get out:

```
<Catalog xml:lang="NB-NO">
...
</Catalog>
```

I've tried to define the attribute "xml:lang", but it doesn't allow me to use ":" in the schema.

This is the error message I get:

> Invalid 'name' attribute value
>   'xml:lang': The ':' character,
>   hexadecimal value 0x3A, at position 3
>   within the name, cannot be included in
>   a name.

Is there another way to insert a ':' as part of the attribute name in BizTalk?

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I'm using BizTalk 2006 and no orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the xml namespace declaration to the schema

```
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

Beware that this addition will be removed when the schema file is recreated.

Comment: When I try that, BizTalk still complains about the lang attribute not being declared.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<xs:attribute name="xml:lang" />
```

try

```
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" />
```

instead. At least PhpStorm stopped complaining about it.